# Is there a group $G$ with $|G|=8$ and $\chi$ assuming values $-2,-1,0,0,0,0,1,2?$

Tags: group-theory, characters

> I want to understand if there is a group $G$ with $|G|=8$ and a character $\chi$ of $G$ assuming values $-2,-1,0,0,0,0,1,2$.

Let $\rho: G \rightarrow GL(V)$. Because $\chi(1_G)=\dim V$, we must have $\dim V$ being equal to $1$ or $2$. Because $\rho(g)$ must be invertible, we musn't have dimension $1$, because in that case, we would have $\rho(g)=0$...

By Schur's Lemma, if $g_o$ is in the center, $\rho(g_o)= \lambda I$. Because $\rho(g_o^{|g_o|})=I$, this $\lambda$ must be a root of unity and we need $|\lambda|=1$. Therefore $\chi(g_o)=2\lambda$ and $p-$groups have no trivial center so we need $2$, $4$ or $8$ elements with $|\chi (g)|=2$.

We do have $2$ such elements with $|\chi(g)|=2$, so $|Z(G)|=2$. Because $G/Z(G)$ is abelian we need $G' \subset Z(G)$ and because $G$ is not abelian $G'=Z(G)$, so there should be $4$ irreducible characters of dimension $1$.

I cannot seem to get any contradiction, which makes me think I should start looking for a group with these properties... Is there a general strategy for these questions?

Comment: You can check [here](https://people.maths.bris.ac.uk/~matyd/GroupNames/index.html#order8).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I shouldn't have asked this question: turns out it is a straightforward computation if we decompose $\rho$ in terms of irreducible characters $\rho=\oplus_i n_i \rho_i $:

$$\sum_i n_i^2=\left\langle \sum_i n_i\chi_i ,\sum_j n_j\chi_j \right\rangle=\langle \chi ,\chi \rangle=\frac{10}{8}\in \mathbb{Z}$$

This is absurd.

If someone knows of other strategies to tackle such problems in more generality, I would very much like to see them.

Comment: Thank you for sharing. Please don't forget to accept this answer. Also, if you want to ask another question, then ask another question instead of adding it to an answer.

Comment: strategies: orhogonality relations, kernel and center of characters (the degree has the largest absolute value among all character values)

Comment: I have to say your question is very unusual. Most people who learn about characters, encounter the character table of groups of order 8 very early on. But your argument is perhaps the most direct.